# Not getting the text from Edit Field

Tags: blackberry

In my Application, i am adding a check box, a label field and a Edit Field in a Grid Field manager. Then this grid Field manager, i am adding multiple times in Vertical Field manager. So it is looking like List of items. Now when i checked five check box, i am trying to get the text of the correspondent edit field.

This is the code for Grid Field Manager:

```
int c[] = {screenWidth/6, (screenWidth)/3, (screenWidth)/2};
    gm = new GridFieldManager(c, Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
    Logger.out("Grocery", "Here it is coming"+i);
    cbfChecked = new CustomCheckBoxField();
    cbfChecked.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() 
    {
        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
        {
            if(checked[i] == false)
            {
                checked[i] = true;
            }
            else if(checked[i] ==  true)
            {
                checked[i] = false;
                Logger.out("Grocery", "It is UnChecked" +checked[i]);
            }
        }
    });
    gm.add(cbfChecked);
    Logger.out("Grocery", "Adding first Label Field");
    LabelFieldCustom lfFrom = new LabelFieldCustom((String) m_vtrItems.elementAt(i),Color.BROWN,FONT_FAMILY_0_SF_AS_16,Field.FIELD_LEFT);
    gm.add(lfFrom);
    Logger.out("Grocery", "Adding second Label Field");
    efcAmount = new EditFieldCustom(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("dob_text_box.png"), 25);
    efcAmount.setMargin(new XYEdges(30, 0, 0, 0));
    gm.add(efcAmount);
    return gm;
```

Here i am adding the grid field manager multiple times:

```
for (int i = 0;i < m_vtrItems.size();i++)
    {

        vfm.add(getRow(i));
        vfm.add(new SeparatorField(SeparatorField.NON_FOCUSABLE));

    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: You didn't use a standard EditField, post your implementation of EditFieldCustom. And what was your code for retrieving text?

Comment: I solved this problem. How can i make it as resolve?

Comment: you can answer your question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. Now i am taking the Edit Field array.